# How to print pandas.dataframe.head without cutting long parameters

Tags: pandas

For example , how to avoid this:

```
    column1                              column2 
0  [4623,236236,2362,626226, ...         64662626
1  [6363,554644,6346,346363, ...         73473473
2  [9543,543674,9806,134736, ...         67457733
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `display.max_colwidth` option to `-1` , check [set_options](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html#pandas-set-option) doc for details.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```

**Sample Code**

```
import random
import pandas as pd

d = { 'column1' : [random.sample(xrange(100), 100) for i in range(3)],
          ' column2' : [ random.randint(1000000,10000000) for i in range(3)]}


df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**Without `set_option`**

```
>>> df
    column2                                            column1
0   7746029  [63, 11, 86, 52, 48, 37, 47, 2, 25, 44, 72, 45...
1   9747244  [27, 34, 0, 88, 46, 39, 89, 78, 23, 1, 47, 9, ...
2   2387014  [45, 63, 26, 22, 7, 90, 92, 44, 99, 19, 17, 91...
```

**With `set_option`**

```
>>> pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
>>> df
    column2  \
0  7746029    
1  9747244    
2  

2387014 

column1  
    0  [63, 11, 86, 52, 48, 37, 47, 2, 25, 44, 72, 45, 36, 14, 31, 55, 21, 0, 93, 74, 30, 91, 6, 20, 54, 41, 40, 38, 79, 46, 73, 42, 97, 64, 81, 10, 77, 69, 3, 78, 70, 85, 84, 66, 4, 9, 50, 59, 98, 58, 22, 57, 18, 90, 95, 35, 12, 34, 99, 80, 1, 7, 87, 82, 33, 39, 68, 83, 27, 28, 76, 23, 17, 8, 92, 32, 5, 19, 62, 15, 65, 49, 53, 61, 43, 94, 13, 29, 89, 26, 24, 88, 71, 16, 96, 51, 67, 75, 60, 56]  
    1  [27, 34, 0, 88, 46, 39, 89, 78, 23, 1, 47, 9, 14, 70, 95, 44, 17, 30, 40, 82, 92, 58, 6, 3, 72, 52, 74, 84, 54, 67, 69, 97, 75, 90, 4, 24, 93, 94, 15, 43, 38, 73, 81, 22, 99, 64, 56, 33, 50, 83, 20, 80, 79, 57, 26, 32, 60, 2, 8, 49, 87, 10, 62, 85, 65, 11, 7, 16, 77, 45, 31, 91, 71, 28, 48, 13, 42, 86, 51, 41, 19, 59, 21, 18, 76, 66, 55, 12, 98, 36, 68, 53, 37, 96, 35, 5, 25, 29, 61, 63]  


 2  [45, 63, 26, 22, 7, 90, 92, 44, 99, 19, 17, 91, 57, 47, 88, 39, 9, 23, 59, 33, 94, 93, 66, 43, 11, 24, 18, 58, 97, 53, 15, 98, 29, 34, 48, 80, 40, 10, 87, 41, 49, 52, 86, 95, 0, 65, 3, 81, 84, 74, 61, 21, 20, 67, 8, 51, 55, 38, 69, 60, 27, 62, 72, 6, 4, 50, 46, 56, 82, 35, 2, 77, 68, 54, 89, 70, 75, 85, 16, 79, 32, 78, 31, 1, 42, 73, 12, 28, 30, 76, 37, 5, 83, 13, 64, 96, 14, 71, 25, 36]  
    >>>
```

**EDIT-1**

In order to print column with  huge string/list values you may want to add following setting to the code.

`pd.set_option('display.max_seq_items', None)`

I tried with columns of list values ~10,000 and it print perfectly.

As per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html)

> display.max_seq_items : int or None
>
> when pretty-printing a long sequence, no more then max_seq_items will be printed. If items are omitted, they will be denoted by the addition of ”...” to the resulting string.
>
> If set to None, the number of items to be printed is unlimited. [default: 100] [currently: 100]

Comment: Thanks , with pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1) the width cutted after ~ 1200 marks. Any idea for more than 1200 marks parameters ?

Comment: Yes, I experimented and adding `pd.set_option('display.max_seq_items', None)` seems to be printing large numbers for me (~10,000+)

Comment: I will up-vote as soon as my reputation will be permitted